# Jquery each return only first found element

Tags: jquery, loops, filter, each, break

```
var x = $(".tabularData tr").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("even")||$(this).hasClass("odd")){
            RETURN ONLY FIRST FOUND ELEMENT, WEATHER EVEN OR ODD
            CURRENT CODE IS RETURNING ALL ELEMENTS
            //return $(this);
        }
});
```

`return $(this)` is return all elements with even|odd whereas i need only return first found element.

Comment: "return"? Do you want to change the jQuery collection to contain only the first qualifying element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I 'm not misunderstanding your intent, you can do this much more easily with

```
var $x = $(".tabularData tr").filter(".odd, .even").first();
```

However, do you really need the "odd or even" test? Since every row is either odd or even, it sounds like it would be much simpler to just do

```
var $x = $(".tabularData tr:first");
```

Comment: awesome, thumbs up for you :)

Comment: i was not need first element but first element that has class even or odd. above code is correct :)